# Testing HTTP using Kiwi/Nocilla

Tags: web-services, unit-testing, testing, kiwi, nocilla

I just started developing an app that connects to [this URL](http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=USD&to=EUR&q=1) and retrieves the rate exchange for a given pair of currencies.

I need to test the HTTP request and I ended up learning about Kiwi and Nocilla. However, I'm completely new to any kind of testing and there's not a lot of information about Nocilla that can help me to get started.

I added all the `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` and `NSURLConnectionDelegate` methods to the `ViewController` of my single view application, and the data retrieved from the URL is stored in `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableData *receivedData;`. When I run the program everything works as expected but I haven't been able to pass the test I wrote:

```
SPEC_BEGIN(URLConnectionSpec)

__block URLConnectionAppDelegate *app_delegate;
__block URLConnectionViewController *view_controller;

describe(@"URLConnection", ^{
    beforeAll(^{
        [[LSNocilla sharedInstance] start];

        app_delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [[app_delegate shouldNot] beNil];
        view_controller = app_delegate.viewController;
    });

    afterAll(^{
        [[LSNocilla sharedInstance] stop];
    });

    afterEach(^{        
        [[LSNocilla sharedInstance] clearStubs];
    });

    context(@"When testing", ^{
        it(@"should do something", ^{
            stubRequest(@"GET", @"http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=USD&to=EUR&q=1");

            [view_controller beginCommunication];

            [[expectFutureValue([NSString stringWithUTF8String:[view_controller.receivedData bytes]]) shouldEventuallyBeforeTimingOutAfter(2)] equal:@"{\"to\": \"EUR\", \"rate\": 0.76610740799999999, \"from\": \"USD\", \"v\": 0.76610740799999999}"];
        });
    });
});

SPEC_END
```

I'm sorry for the long snippet of code.

The test always failed with this message

```
URLConnection_WhenTesting_ShouldDoSomething] : 'URLConnection, When testing, should do something' [FAILED], expected subject to equal "{"to"： "EUR", "rate"： 0.76610740799999999, "from"： "USD", "v"： 0.76610740799999999}", got ""
```

I tried changing the time to even 10 seconds hoping that the test finished too early but I got the same results. I don't know why 'receivedData' is empty.

I would really appreciate any help

Comment: The general structure of the Kiwi test looks ok. Can you show the code for `stubRequest`? And are you certain that all of your variables (`view_controller`, etc.) are non-nil?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. `stubRequest` is part of [Nocilla](https://github.com/luisobo/Nocilla), I didn't implemented myself.
All the variables in view_controller are initialized to nil, and the `NSMutableData` that contains the data received from the URL is initialized in `connectionDidFinishLoading:connection`. However I don't know why just when testing, this function or any other related related with `NSURLConnectionDelegate` or `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`, aren't being called.

Comment: The code for `stubRequest` looks pretty reasonable, looks like that should work fine with Kiwi since it just operates on `LSNocilla sharedInstance`. Could you try stepping through the debugger or adding some `NSLog` statements to `beginCommunication`?

Comment: I cannot believe I made such mistake...The whole point of using `stubRequest` is to simulate the connection to an URL, which means, during testing the app will "connect" to `stubRequest` and since this function does not return the same data the real URL does, well...I think you see the problem in here. After using NSLog as you suggested I could see that everything was working how it was supposed to. Would you mind writing your comment as an answer so I can check it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See discussion in comments: the overall structure of the Kiwi test looks good, the Nocilla `stubRequest` function call doesn't seem to result in the response that the test is expecting.

Perhaps you could use `andReturnRawResponse` to set up the expected response data. Something like this (assuming I got the Nocilla syntax correct):

```
NSData *rawData = ...
stubRequest(...).andReturnRawResponse(rawData);
[view_controller beginCommunication];
[expectFutureValue([view_controller.receivedData bytes])
  shouldEventuallyBeforeTimingOutAfter(2)] equal:rawData.bytes];
```